# H264 -> Container using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, c++, containers, h.264

I have raw H264 video data that I want to wrap into some kind of container format so that I can play it in a video player like WMP or VLC, and I want to do this in .NET (C#), or C++. What is the easiest approach? Does anyone know of a free/open source SDK that would make this easy?

Comment: Have you checked out the API of the mkv splitter library?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply play it through a WPF media element if the computer has the appropriate Codec's installed.